# Gettext isnt translating the text in php

Tags: php, gettext

I'm at a loss of what I'm doing wrong. Gettext is enabled, according to phpinfo(). I have checked out the locales that the system uses and generated the danish ones, so the language alias exists in the system.

I don't know if I have set things up right in the php file shown below:

```
<?php
// I18N support information here
$language = "da_DK.utf8";

$p = putenv("LANG=" . $language);
echo 'pputenv: '.$p;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


$s = setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
echo 'setlocale: '.$s;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";

$b = bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
echo 'bindtextdomain: '.$b;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$b2 = bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
echo 'bind_textdomain_codeset: '.$b2;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$t = textdomain($domain);
echo 'textdomain: '.$t;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

if (!function_exists("gettext"))
{
    echo "gettext is not installed\n";
}
else
{
    echo "gettext is supported\n";
}

echo "<br><br>";

//phpinfo();


echo _("HELLO_WORLD").'<br>';
echo _('Testing Translation...').'<br>';
?>
```

The result I get from that file is:

```
pputenv: 1

setlocale: da_DK.utf8

bindtextdomain: /var/www/sites/interna/Locale

bind_textdomain_codeset: UTF-8

textdomain: messages

gettext is supported 

HELLO_WORLD
Testing Translation...
```

Lastly, this is the .po file use for the danish translation:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: danish interna\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-07-08 15:32+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-07-08 15:32+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: Danish\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: ../..\n"

#: ../../index.php:49
msgid "HELLO_WORLD"
msgstr "Hej verden"

#: ../../index.php:50
msgid "Testing Translation..."
msgstr "Tester"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you compiled your .po file to /var/www/sites/interna/Locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo?

Comment: Yes. Well.. I use Poedit, which does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So I made it work, yet Im not sure where exactly I went wrong. I noticed I was missing the "LC_MESSAGES" folder for my danish files. Which was pretty silly :)

But there was a bunch of other things I tweaked a little and the good news is that it all works now!